# SSRS format total minutes into total HH:MM:SS

Tags: visual-studio, reporting-services, ssrs-2012, sql-server-data-tools

The current report expression presents the data in Days:Hours:Minutes:Seconds

```
=cstr(floor((sum(Fields!phoneInOutbound.Value) / 86400))) & " days " & 
cstr(floor(((sum(Fields!phoneInOutbound.Value) Mod 86400) / 3600))) & ":" & 
cstr(floor((((sum(Fields!phoneInOutbound.Value) Mod 86400) Mod 3600) / 60))) & ":" & 
cstr(floor(((sum(Fields!phoneInOutbound.Value) Mod 86400) Mod 3600) Mod 60))
```

I am trying to get it to show total Hours:Minutes:Seconds.

So far I have only managed to get minutes:seconds using the following expression;

```
=cstr(floor((sum(Fields!phoneInOutbound.Value) / 60))) & " : " & 
cstr(floor(((sum(Fields!phoneInOutbound.Value) Mod 60))))
```

Any idea how to reconfigure so I can get total hours:minutes:seconds?

Comment: Have you tried just using the original statement minus the first `cstr` statement? It seems thats how you got the minutes:Seconds. Can you alter the `Select` statement? That might be easier to get your date formatted correctly before you put it into SSRS.

Comment: Hi Alex, thanks for your reply. I have tried just omitting the first cstr statement but got the result of "17:18:30". As the original was "1 day 17:18:30" I'm looking for a result like "41:18:30"

Hope this makes sense! I'm very new to SSRS and still trying to wrap my head around it.

Comment: Thank you!! Got it.
=cstr(floor((sum(Fields!phoneInOutbound.Value) / 86400*24))) & ":" & 
cstr(floor((((sum(Fields!phoneInOutbound.Value) Mod 86400) Mod 3600) / 60))) & ":" & 
cstr(floor(((sum(Fields!phoneInOutbound.Value) Mod 86400) Mod 3600) Mod 60))

Comment: I moved my comment down as an answer, if that's the route you took could you please mark it as such. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so your basically going to need to add the first statement (Where it originally gets days) plus the second statement (where it was originally hours). You can either change the first statement to get the days than days * 24 to get days back to hours THAN + 2nd statement. There's probably an easier way, not sure what your data set looks like or even what database your reading from. Just trying to get you thinking in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

If I was you I would handle it on sql side and just use ssrs as a place to hold the data. You can make this as easy or as complex you want. When I mean complex i mean you get the data from Minutes filed and then add "min" + seconds value + "sec" to it. By wrapping the whole thing in another named query and creating a calculated field. Personally not a big fan of leveraging SSRS for doing calculations as you are using report server's memory to do this (which should be used for reporting not handling calculations) BUT if this method is easy for you then more power to ya. Below is a sample code to handle this on SQL side.

```
create table #temp_time_test (
    phoneInOutbound_IN datetime
    ,phoneInOutbound_OUT datetime
    )

    insert into #temp_time_test values 
    ('11/06/2018 12:24:13.790','11/06/2018 12:34:13.790')



    select DATEDIFF(MINUTE,phoneInOutbound_IN,phoneInOutbound_OUT) from #temp_time_test
```